# Prevent overwrite of Upload File via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm using following code through the Microsoft Graph API dot.net sdk

```
using (Stream fileStream = file.InputStream)
            {
                DriveItem uploadedFile = await graphClient
                    .Drives[DRIVE_ID]
                     .Root.ItemWithPath($"{root}{relative}{file.FileName}")
                        .Content.Request()
                        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);


            }
```

to upload a simple file to OneDrive. Is it possible to prevent the file upload if the file already exists?

Update

The Microsoft Graph Documentation has been updated here a snippet from it:

***Request body***

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession

No request body is required. However, you can specify a request body to provide additional data about the file being uploaded.
For example, to control the behavior if the filename is already taken, you can specify the conflict behavior property in the body of the request.

```
{
    "item": {
        "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately no. In order to prevent file override (which also creates a new version) you have to first check if the file with the path already exists. You can do that programmatically by listing parent folder contents and checking by filename.

Comment: thanks for your reply, that's kinda disappointing, maybe something comes up in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use @microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior. More here: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm

Comment: thanks lolet, good tip to just look at the onedrive api straight

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite of a file when using MS Graph API to upload a file via drive item update (`PUT /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content`) can be prevented by specifying the `if-match` header with an arbitrary value (like "0" which shall never match the etag/ctag).

The API call then, for an existing item, shall return `HTTP 412 Precondition-failed`. For a non-existing file, the API call shall go through and create the file with the specified content.

This works with "small file uploads". However for "resumable uploads" you can use the conflict behaviour flag to override the behaviour.